# Motorcycle rentals in Spain, licence restrictions

Tags: spain, rental, driving-licenses, motorcycles

I'm planning a 3 day motorcycling trip around Seville, Spain. I'm from EU, and have had a full motorcycle licence for less than a year.

The rentals I've found on internet so far seem to require that licence has been had for 1-3 years. Is this a universal rule, or is there hope to find smaller rental place that doesn't have this requirement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The license held restriction is normally required by the insurance companies the rental places use. If you haven't had your license very long, then you're considered a higher risk due to the lack of experience.

You should find that some places will have a different insurance policy that can be offered, which would let you ride with your license, but likely with both a higher excess and a higher daily rate.

Some big places will have this already worked out as standard, so if you ring them they should be able to quote straight off. Alternately, a smaller rental place ought to be able to ring up their insurers and arrange a one-off for you, possibly for an admin fee (in addition to the higher premiums and excesses....). I'd suggest you ring up a few places and see what they can do.

Comment: Thanks for answering, this gives me hope a deal can be arranged. Will have to start contacting rental places well in advance!